# Get column reference after scrolled

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to see if it's possible to find out via `VBA` what the furthest left visible column is on the active screen.

i.e. scrolled across to column AB and want to be able to pick up either a column number or the letters "AB".

No idea if it's even possible so not got anything to work with.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried.

Comment: as stated i am not sure if it's possible so i have no code to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .VisibleRange

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Address
End Sub
```

[image]